# Getting users and groups that have access to a Power BI Report using REST API

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, rest

Currently it is possible to get the users (Active Directory) of a Group(or Workspace) using the following REST API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/groups/getgroupusers

We have a specific need in our project wherein we need to access the users and groups (Active Directory) who have access to a Report.

Is there a way to do this using Power BI REST API?

The overview page and the menu points below it do not seem to support this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [GetReportUsersAsAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/reports-get-report-users-as-admin). Currently there are limits on how often you can call it.

Comment: Is it possible to modify this list using REST API? Add/remove users, for example, the ones having direct access to a report?

Comment: @AntonK not sure. We let the report creators manage access via the PowerBI website.